# Payment method showing as disabled in admin area despite being enabled

Tags: admin, payment, payment-methods, adminform

We're having an issue where PayPal Express checkout is shown as disabled in the Magento admin area regardless of what the actual status is in the database:

[image: Payment method shown as disabled]

What's strange is that even the HTML on the page seems to show the status as enabled:

`<select id="payment_express_checkout_required_enable_express_checkout" name="groups[express_checkout_required][fields][enable_express_checkout][value]" class="paypal-enabler paypal-ec-enabler shared shared-payment-paypal_express-active requires requires-payment_express_checkout_required_express_checkout select" disabled="">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Yes</option>
    <option value="0">No</option>
</select>`

We can also see in the database that this payment method is actually enabled:

```
# config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value
'425', 'default', '0', 'payment/paypal_express/active', '1'
```

Unfortunately, if we save the config from the admin area, it then sets this payment method to actually be disabled, and we can't change it back from the UI as the option is always disabled (as in the HTML element has a disabled attribute).

In the debugger, I can see that this select is disabled by line 14874 of the inline Javascript on that page, but it's not clear why.

**My question is, why is this select getting disabled and displaying a misleading value?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amusingly it turned out this was as simple as the `X.COM Application Id` setting being required to enable PayPal Express Checkout.

Completing that field re-enables the PayPal settings.

[image]

Comment: @JasonTipton: will do when I'm allowed to in 2 days!

Comment: Oh that's interesting, I didn't know about that limitation.